# passing values from one function to another with special charecters

Tags: javascript, blob

I'm passing the value from one function to another function in javascript. That value has the special charecters(blob data).here is the sample blob data

```
    for( i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){
               var j = 'blob:f09a28da-58f8-4866-a2f3-462a24d05ae7';
              $('.preview-area').append('<span class = "image' + i + '"><img src="' + objectUrl + '"/><a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "remove_image('+j+')">Remove'+i+'</a></span>');

            }
function remove_image(j){

        alert(j);
    }
```

i want to pass this value to another function. if i use escape function it shows  the syntax error  identifier starts immediately after numeric literal.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the code where you are trying to pass the value.

Comment: @Pointy - if i pass the value it shows the error syntax error identifier starts immediately after numeric literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not just "passing the value" — you're creating new code.  That means you have to introduce quotes around the string, just as you did when you typed in the assignment.

```
      $('.preview-area').append('<span class = "image' + i + '"><img src="' + objectUrl + '"/><a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "remove_image(&#34;'+j+'&#34;)">Remove'+i+'</a></span>');
```

Because you're adding the function call as part of some HTML markup, you can use HTML entities to escape the quotes.